# Docker container can't resolve host server IP

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-compose, iptables

I see lot of similar network issues for docker but nothing that helps me understand what's wrong here and how to solve it.

Basically I do a curl to the public IP from the container and is not able to reach the server:

from the host (I've replaced the IP by XXX for security reasons):

```
root@vultr ~]# curl http://207.246.XXX.XXX -vvvv
* About to connect() to 207.246.XXX.XXX port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 207.246.XXX.XXX...
* Connected to 207.246.XXX.XXX (207.246.XXX.XXX) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1

[root@vultr ~]# curl http://google.com -vvvv
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4008:80e::200e...
* Connected to google.com (2607:f8b0:4008:80e::200e) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

from the container:

```
bash-4.4# curl http://207.246.XXX.XXX -vvvv
* Rebuilt URL to: http://207.246.XXX.XXX/
*   Trying 207.246.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 207.246.XXX.XXX port 80 failed: Host is unreachable
* Failed to connect to 207.246.XXX.XXX port 80: Host is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 207.246.XXX.XXX port 80: Host is unreachable

bash-4.4# curl http://google.com -vvvv
* Rebuilt URL to: http://google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.3.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.3.78) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

I would like to understand what's going on exactly, how do I configure docker correctly to resolve the IP and access the url same way the host is doing it.

Thanks